# mapreduce - Intermediate key and output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

For each intermediate key, each reducer task can emit:

- As many final key-value pairs as desired. There are no restrictions on the types of those 'n' key-value pairs (i.e., they can be heterogeneous).

OR

- As many final key-value pairs as desired, as long as all the keys have the same type and all the values have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

"As many as you wish" is true, there is no restriction on the number of output pairs, (as long as there is enough space of course).

The type of output keys and the type of output values is predefined in the main method (in the Driver class of the old API), as well as the type of map output keys and values.
Those are set in the following way:

```
conf.setOutputKeyClass(VIntWritable.class); //just an example
conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class); //just an example
```

and

```
conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(VIntWritable.class); //just an example
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class); //just an example
```

respectively.

You only need to set the type of map output, if it is different than the reduce output.

If you want to output more types, then you can use [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html).